# Physical path of IIS Web App Manage - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, iis, azure-devops, web-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Physical path is getting wrong of IIS Web App Manage while releasing the project. One path is the actual path I given in the Physical path (%SystemDrive%/DevOps/WebApi)field and the release moving only to the IIS default path that is "c:/inetpub/wwwroot"
[image]

yellow colored files are from wwwroot and the red color is actual release.
I need to deploy under Default Web Site not under the Sites folder
Pipeline
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to deploy under Default Web Site not under the Sites folder

If you want to deploy Web App under Default Web Site, you could specify the Website name `Api` instead of `/Api` in the Stage:

[image]

[image]

Note: If those yellow colored files are generated by the web app you deploy `Api`, you need to check the Physical path in the IIS of your default web page.

**Update:**

> I need to deploy under the " Default Web Site" because only port 80 is
> open for public access

To achieve this, we need to provide "Virtual Application" input as `Api` in the `IIS web app deploy` task：

[image]

Now, I could deploy the web app under the " Default Web Site":

[image]

Comment: IIS server physical path is  "c:inetpub/wwwroot"  but in my 2nd snapshort you can see the changed physical path

Comment: @user2119324, You mean that even if your address in the pipeline is changed to Devops\WeApi, the web app will still be deployed to the physical path c:\inetpub/wwwroot, right? Have you tried to clean up the files of c:\inetpub/wwwroot and then run the pipeline?

Comment: It's not working. Updated the question, please check the steps I did for release pipeline (last 3 snapshot) please help I am new in azure devops

Comment: @user2119324, I got it, thanks for your update. Do you want to deploy your web app in the new webiste `Api`, not under the default website?

Comment: I need to deploy under the " Default Web Site" because only port 80 is open for public access

Comment: @user2119324, Thanks for you reply. I updated the answer, please check if it helps you. Have a nice day!